# Looping on list in powershell command inside python

Tags: python, powershell, email

I am trying to send email using Powershell and Python in Tabular format with heading and a list of values, but in mail i get the table, heading and empty cell.

```
res = ['1234', '235']

powershell_script = r'''
***to from email & server here***
$resArray = $res -split ','

$tableBody = $resArray | ForEach-Object {
    "<tr><td>$($_)</td></tr>"
} | Out-String

$body = @"
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Table of 'res' Values</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
  $tableBody
</table>
</body>
</html>
"@

$emailParams = ....
    Send-MailMessage @emailParams

'''
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command",res, powershell_script], check=True, text=True)
```

Mails I received is 'Table of 'res' Values
'Value'
UPDATE : Using following Powershell code

```
$emailParams = @{ 
   To = $toEmail 
   From = $fromEmail 
   Subject = $subject 
   Body = $body 
   BodyAsHtml = $true 
   SmtpServer = $smtpServer 
   Port = $smtpPort 
} 
# Send the email 
try { 
   Send-MailMessage @emailParams Write-Host "Email sent successfully!" 
} 
catch { Write-Host "An error occurred while sending the email: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
}
```

Comment: Try -BodyAsHtml : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: rest of code i used '$emailParams = @{
    To = $toEmail
    From = $fromEmail
    Subject = $subject
    Body = $body
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    SmtpServer = $smtpServer
    Port = $smtpPort
}

# Send the email
try {
    Send-MailMessage @emailParams
    Write-Host "Email sent successfully!"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "An error occurred while sending the email: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}'

Comment: @jdweng check my last comment plz

Comment: New code looks good.  Does it work?  Shouldn't it be FROM : Body = $body TO : Body = $tableBody

Comment: @jdweng tablebody already inside html

Comment: Body = $tableBody
+     ~~~~
Duplicate keys 'Body' are not allowed in hash literals.

Comment: The body should start with your tag <h2> The cmdlet is already adding the tags html, and body.  The style should be attributes in the table like <table style="width:100%">